# how can i change the pattern in php?

Tags: sql, mysql, design-patterns

i got this pattern for searching purpose for mysql from third party javascript. im assuming its html pattern, which can be converted, anyone have any idea on this?

```
pattern A%5B%D9%8B-%D9%93%D9%B0%5D*L%5B%D9%8B-%D9%93%D9%B0%5D*L%5B%D9%8B-%D9%93%D9%B0%5D*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks urlencoded and has some unicode charecters in it.

`A[Ù‹-Ù“Ù°]*L[Ù‹-Ù“Ù°]*L[Ù‹-Ù“Ù°]*`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a query string - where values are encoded.

See http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/tagpages/text.htm for more information.